# BufEnter events triggered with a mouse click in gvim: line('.') appear to return a wrong value. How to fix it?

Tags: gvim, autocmd

Consider the following auto-group

```
augroup Test
    au!
    autocmd BufEnter * :echo line('.')
augroup END
```

and open two different buffers in split windows.

When using commands such as `wincmd p`, then the echoed lines are the lines where the cursor actually lies on, which is what I would expect.

However, if I switch windows by mouse click, then the displayed lines are not the lines where the the cursor lies in, but are the previous lines where the cursor was last time that such a buffer has been visited.

I wish that when I switch windows through mouse click then the echoed line is the actual line where the cursor landed.

Why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Probably a mouse click triggers entering the buffer and _then_ cursor movement?

Comment: Yes, that is likely. But then we would need a BufEnterMouse event for working with gui :D